# Creating Zipcode US map in R and adding Legend on Map

Tags: r

I am new to R and need help. I need to make a map of zipcode. The dataframe is as follows -

```
Zipcode   plpn
31139     138
85941     58
85349     104.01
87305     101
86515     98.08
79849     96.98
```

I want to plot this on US map and apply color by plpn variable.

```
     plpn   color
     0-50   light blue
   50-100   blue 
     100+   dark blue
```

Can you kindly tell me the easiest way to do it in R ?

Note - I wanted through the webpages on this but the code seem bit complicated for me.(https://www.r-bloggers.com/my-first-r-package-zipcode/)

I tried the following -

```
    library(maps)
    library(zipcode)
    data(zipcode)

    setwd("C:/Users/rkpanda/Documents/TEMP/Feb2017/")
    mktng <- read.csv(file="zipcode_mrktng.csv", header=T, sep = ",")
    mktng2 <- merge(mktng, zipcode, by.x='postal_cd', by.y = 'zip')
    mktng3 <- subset(mktng2, plpn_by_credit > 50)
    map("state")
    points( mktng3$longitude, mktng3$latitude, pch= 20, cex= 0.5,     col="blue")
```

Is there a way to apply label (city name associated with zipcode) to the dots that are appearing on the map ?

Comment: You can start by finding a shape file of all zip-codes in the U.S. These are publically available. Then you can create a choropleth from your data using a number of packages. If this question hasn't been answered by the time I get home, I'd love to get more into it.

Comment: I was trying to use choropleth as mentioned in - 
https://www.trulia.com/blog/tech/the-choroplethr-package-for-r/

When I use the code mentioned for zipcode in this page, I got following warning message. 

> choroplethr(df, lod="zip", num_buckets=1)
Warning message:
In choroplethr(df, lod = "zip", num_buckets = 1) :
  This function is deprecated as of choroplethr version 2.0.0. Please use ?state_choropleth, ?county_choropleth, ?zip_map

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by apply legend city name associated with zipcode?

Comment: Sorry, I meant labeling by city name for each zip code.  I have the city name in my dataset. I am not able to put it on map.

Comment: `text(mktng$longitude, mktng$latitude, labels = mktng$city)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the shapefiles from here:

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html

This is slow because it is plotting the entire US but it works:

```
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

shp <- readOGR('shapefiles/cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k', 
    'cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shpDF <- fortify(shp)
shpData <- shp@data
shpData$AWATER10 <- as.numeric(shpData$AWATER10)
shpData$id <- row.names(shpData)
shpDF <- shpDF %>%
  left_join(shpData, by = 'id')

ggplot(shpDF) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group , fill = (AWATER10)), 
            color = 'gray') +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlim(-125, -65) +
  ylim(24, 50)
```

The end result image isnt that great at the zip code level. The resolution of zip codes is too small.

To add in your own data just left join to the shpDF on the ZCTA5CE10 field.